# Routes being declared in a config vs routes being declared by their controller

Tags: javascript, routes

I spent most of today mulling this over. There are two applications I'm working on - an ExtJS4 powered application and a Backbone powered application. In both cases they are single page apps - the user doesn't leave the page, so they can 'pause' what they're doing or looking at to react to another point of interest.

In the ExtJS4 case, I'm using a sort of home grown route system where, when the application boots, it asks all of its controllers "What routes do you respond to?". This has, so far as I can tell, a couple of advantages -

1. The routes are defined on the controller, so remove the controller and there's no need to update a config file.
2. The application is easier to add controllers to, and it seems to make it much more modular.
3. Changing routes, or parameters doesn't require the application to change, just the controller (and since the controller handles the route internally, it's very well confined).

The problem is, I haven't seen any frameworks or applications so far that do something like this. I don't know why - is this such a terrible practice that it doesn't make it into a production environment? Or have I just not been working on projects that use it..? The Backbone based application is based on some crazy hackjob code, so today I rewrote most of it using the same basic format. It dropped the complexity of the code immensely, leading me to wonder if this was a 'too good to be true situation'.

Psuedo code:

```
controller
    routes: ['/bookmarks', '/bookmarks/(:action)/(:id)', '/bookmarks/(:action)']
    init: fn ()
       this.application.registerRoutes(this.routes, this);
       //other code to set up views and such
    routeHandler: fn (route, params)
       //tells the application to switch the visible stuff to this thing's 
       //main view, declared elsewhere
       this.application.showView(this.view) 
       switch(params.action)
          case "edit":
             //some internal stuff to show the editing field for the ID passed..
             this.showEditor();
             this.loadRecordById(params.id)
          case "new":
             //some internal stuff 
             this.showEditor();
```

So, I guess the question is: "Is this bad practice, and why? If not, why isn't this used elsewhere? Too difficult or messy to set up with other languages? Can you foresee something coming down the pipe that will bite me later on?"

Thanks.

EDIT:
I realized a few downsides last night -

1. registering all the possible routes requires all of the controllers to start. But, even then (particularly for JS) there is an easy way around that.
2. If I want to change a route, I've got to track down the controller that manages that particular route. Granted, that shouldn't be an issue if my routes are appropriately named.
3. It'd be difficult to track down alias routes - i.e. /marketing_page really being /pages/3.. but this isn't how the application works, so in this case it's kind of a moot point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am trying to figure out how the user got to `/bookmarks/edit/5`, where do I look?

With your approach, I have to find the controller; who knows where you put it. Maybe you're following a naming convention, or maybe not. Maybe the route is something more like `/users/domenic/edit/preferences`---I have no idea what the controller is going to be there.

With the conventional approach, the route wiring is separated from the controllers. There's only one place to look if I want to know where a route goes. I won't accidentally add two responses for the same route, because the wirings would be right next to each other---whereas if I put my routes on my controllers, I could spend quite some time wondering "why isn't my action getting triggered?" when it's because some other controller, somewhere else, is already responding to that route.

In general, the idea is **separation of concerns**. It's not the controller's job to worry about routing: it's the controller's job to expose actions, which may be called in a variety of ways (routes being one of them). Controller responsibility is then very tightly scoped (**single responsibility principle**: there's only one axis of change for the controller). Routing concerns can be separated into a dedicated routing table, which decouples the routes from their implementations and makes them easy to change (**open-close principle**). If you later want to change `/users/domenic/edit/preferences` to use the `preferences` controller instead of the `users` controller, you don't have to edit your controllers at all: which is as it should be, since they shouldn't need to worry about routing.

Comment: And this is why being a sole programmer sometimes really isn't the best way to go. No more than a few hours after typing it out to the internet do I realize there's a problem, and then you confirm it.

Comment: That's what we're here for! :D